# Pycharm having issues installing pandas (using python 2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, pycharm

I am trying to install pandas on Pycharm but, I'm having issues installing pandas. I have tried using pip install pandas but it's not working, could someone help, please.

Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pandas/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pandas/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '_ssl.c:499: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version'),)) - skipping

Comment: Try: `pip install --upgrade pip --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org`

Comment: @Rafael this is the output Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '_ssl.c:499: error:1407742E:SSL routin
es:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version'),)) - skipping
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in d:\codetest\asr_practice\venv\lib\site-packages (10.0.1)